# How to display a value being passed?

Tags: php, forms, post, loops, foreach

How can I display this value in the loop ?

```
   echo '<input type="hidden" name="eg_payamt_'.$i.'"  id="amount_post_'.$i.'"  value="">';
```

this code is being passed into next code by POST

On the next page,
Could it be like this ?

```
 foreach($_POST["eg_payamt_"] as $key => $payamt)
      {
        echo "eg_payamt_$key => $payamt\n <br>"; 
      }
```

I don't see any results,

Do you guys have any ideas ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the name of the input element -- *all* input elements like this will have the same name:

```
<input type="hidden" name="eg_payamt[]" value="whatever" />
```

And then when you access `$_POST['eg_payamt']` it will already be an array, so your code will work almost as-is (you need to lose a couple of underscores).

Comment: Ok, I'll try, like this :                  echo '<input type="hidden" name="eg_payamt_[]"  id="amount_post_'.$i.'" value="" >';

Comment: @RickAnt: That's fine as well. Although you don't need the trailing underscore.